# How Stay the class ( active ) in element after reload page?

Tags: jquery

I have the list of menu and want to stay the active class on any element I clicked after redirect to another page or refresh the page

code of list :

```
 <div id="myTab">
    <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="{{ url('home') }}">home</a>
    <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="{{ url('prfile') }}">prfile</a>
    <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="{{ url('setting') }}">setting</a>
 </div>
```

code of js I'd tried but not working :

```
  $(function(){
    var url = window.location.pathname;  
    var activePage = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
    $('#myTab > a').each(function(){  
        var currentPage = this.href.substring(this.href.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
        if (activePage == currentPage) {
            $(this).parent().addClass('active'); 
        } 
    });
  });
```

Comment: debug and figure out why. console.log() is your friend.

Comment: @epascarello nothing show in console :(

Comment: did you add console.log() lines to see what `activePage` and `currentPage` are? Does the script find the elements, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Based on markup shown it doesn't make sense adding the class to the parent of the `<a>` which is `#myTab`.

Should be able to do a direct comparison to `location.href` to simplify this also

```
$(function() {
  $('#myTab > a').filter(function() {
    return this.href === location.href
  }).addClass('active');
})
```

Comment: How are you verifying it? Are you duplicating that id by chance?

Comment: And do those links exist when page is loaded? Or are they inserted after?

Comment: I want to add class active when I clicked on it , and after that if I reload page the the class stay on it not remove !

Comment: When you click on it no point adding it unless you are using ajax to load content in same page...otherwise it will go to another page right away

Comment: I'm guessing the class is getting added and you need to sort out css

Comment: now I use laravel, the menu when I click on any one bring me to the page depends the menu , so I wanna to static the class in the menu I'd choose ( got it  now haha ?)

Comment: like when I choose profile page it will redirect me to the new page and during this page will be refresh ( got i t )